# store object in ArrayList using another class

Tags: java, arraylist

This is the first code:

```
public class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Person(String name,int age){
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name+","+age;
    }

}
```

Then this is the main class wherein it will show the output:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PersonDatabase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Person> list= new ArrayList<>();
        Person p = new Person("",0);
        int choice =0;
        String listing ="";

        do{
            choice=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"\nChoices:"+"\n[1]Add"+"\n[2]Edit"+"\n[3]Delete"+"\n[4]Search"+"\n[5]View"+"\n[6]Sort"+"\n[7]Exit"+"\nEnter Choice:"));


            switch(choice){
            case 1:
                String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Name:");
                int age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Age:"));
                list.add(new Person(name,age)); 
                break;

            case 2:
                break;

            case 3:
                break;

            case 4:

                break;
            case 5:
                if(!list.isEmpty()){
                    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                        listing+=list.toString();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,listing);
                    }
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR","", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                break;

            case 7:
                break;


            }

        }while(choice!=7);
    }

}
```

I'm sorry if I am not clear with my question but I want to use the ArrayList wherein I store the ArrayList in Person class and I want to view it using the public String toString so it will show the name and age

Comment: No one can possibly understand what you're trying to achieve in the second snippet. But, are you asking How to access the people stored in the `list` arraylist?

Comment: Could create a Persons/People class which either IS A or HAS A `List<Person>` and then implement your own toString() method there? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Again I'm sorry for not being clear well what I'm doing is whatever I add in the list and I will fetch the object from the ArrayList using the toList wherein it will show both the age and name that I inputed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the `Person` object from the list using `list.get(index)` method, then concatenate.

I guess, once you get all the person information, then you want to show. So take out the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,listing);` from for loop. Otherwise keep it inside the loop, as you have currently.

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
     listing += list.get(i).toString() + "\n";  // get the i Person instance from list and call toString()     
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,listing);
```

---

You are doing the `String` concatenation using `+` operator. You can also use the `StringBuilder` class to append all the Person information from the list.

Comment: Thank you it worked and thanks to all the people who helped me :D

Comment: one last question : 

How do you separate your input because it continues like a sentence and not just by line

Comment: Use `\n` new line separator or something which you need.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue is with your case 5: code.

Try

```
case 5:
   if(!list.isEmpty()){
      for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        listing+=list.get(i).toString();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,listing);
     }
  }else{
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR","",
       JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
  }
break;
```

Note the **list.get(i).toString(**) instead of **list.toString()**

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be inserting the Person class correctly inside the ArrayList. So it seems that, if you need to see the contents of your ArrayList using [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), all you need is to override the method [toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) in your Person class. So when you print your ArrayList, it will just call the toString() method for each ArrayList element.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Person> list= new ArrayList<>();
        int choice =0;

        do{
            choice=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"\nChoices:"+"\n[1]Add"+"\n[2]Edit"+"\n[3]Delete"+"\n[4]Search"+"\n[5]View"+"\n[6]Sort"+"\n[7]Exit"+"\nEnter Choice:"));


            switch(choice){
            case 1:
                String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Name:");
                int age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Age:"));
                list.add(new Person(name,age)); 
                break;

            case 2:
                break;

            case 3:
                break;

            case 4:

                break;
            case 5:
                if(!list.isEmpty()){
                    foreach(Person p : list){
                        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
                        message.append(p.toString());
                        message.append("\n"); 
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message.toString());
                    }
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR","", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                break;

            case 7:
                break;


            }

        }while(choice!=7);
    }
```